# Moment generating functions of continous random variables at 0

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, moment-generating-function

I'm studying mgfs of various distributions and I have a doubt about a property of mgfs:
My book says that a common feature of **discrete** function's mgf is that it always exists, and takes value 1 at t=0
It gives this proof for the discrete case:
$$ E(e^0) = E(1)= \sum 1 \space p(x) = 1 $$
How do I do the proof for the continuous case?
$$ E(e^0) = E(1)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 1 \space p(x) = ??? $$

Comment: For a continuous RV, you probably do not mean $p(x)$ but rather $f(x)$, the [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function). For this,

$$
E[e^0] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx = 1.
$$

Comment: You're right, I just copied the formula and forgot to change that, but... How to compute that integral? How does it give 1?

Comment: The integral of the PDF over the entire range is 1 almost by definition.

Comment: For the statement "an mgf exists" to be meaningful, the mgf ought to be defined and finite in some open neighborhood of $0,$ not just at $0$ itself.  But then an mgf does *not* always exist.  The [Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) is a standard example.  By "discrete" your book might mean "of finite support," which implies bounded support (all finite sets of real numbers are bounded). Unfortunately that rules out many important distributions like Poisson, Negative Binomial, Pareto, *etc.*

Answer (score -1):

This is a universal range. What I mean to say is that this support (domain of x) captures all kind random variables domain in it.
For example, a Normal random variable domain is $(-\infty, \infty)$, 
a Beta random variable domain is (0,1),
a gamma random variable domain is $(0,\infty)$ 
So, when you integrate/sum a random variables pdf/pmf over this universal range, it will always be 1.